# java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) Flutter error

Tags: flutter, android-studio, pdf, runtime-error, pdf-viewer

***I have a PDF file of about 800 pages in my app asset folder, I am trying to view this PDF file using the flutter_pdfview package but it gives me the above error.***

Tried lots of methods but didn't work for me

**AndroidMenifest.xml:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

**Method to get and display a PDF file:**

```
Future<File> fromAsset(String asset, String filename) async {
  Completer<File> completer = Completer();

  try {
    var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    File file = File("${dir.path}/$filename");
    var data = await rootBundle.load(asset);
    var bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();
    await file.writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
    completer.complete(file);
  } catch (e) {
    throw Exception('Error parsing asset file!');
  }

  return completer.future;
}
```

**Requesting storage permission:**

```
Future<void> checkStoragePermission() async {
  final status = await Permission.storage.request();
  if (status.isGranted) {
    setState(() {
      isPermitted = true;
    });
    fromAsset('assets/pdf/book.pdf', 'myBook.pdf').then((f) {
      setState(() {
        pathPDF = f.path;
      });
    });


  }else{
    isPermitted=false;
  }
}
```

***I have a PDF file of about 800 pages in my app asset folder, I am trying to view this PDF file using the flutter_pdfview package but it gives me the  error:***

- java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: Which android API are you targeting?

Comment: latest API, I think it is 33 now.